# MongoDB (server v 2.6.7) with C# driver 2.0: How to get the result from InsertOneAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb, async-await, mongodb-.net-driver

I am testing MongoDB (server v 2.6.7)  with the C# driver 2.0.

When I am using the insert function `InsertOneAsync` for a document with an `_id` which exists I am expecting an error like the one you get from the Mongo shell:

> ```
> WriteResult({
>     "nInserted" : 0,
>     "writeError" : {
>             "code" : 11000,
>             "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: mydb.Commands.$_id_  dup key: { : 0.0 }"
>     }})
> ```

But the problem is that the insert with the C# driver does not throw an exception and I can not find the `WriteResult` for the insert.
When I look in the database it seems nothing have happened.

So my question is what to expect from `InsertOneAsync` when inserting an existing `_id`?

The code in Visual Studio:

```
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> commandsCollection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Commands");
var bson = new BsonDocument
        {
            {"_id", i.Value},
            {"label", i.Key}
        };
commandsCollection.InsertOneAsync(bson);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're doing this within an `async` method, then Brduca's answer will work (and is preferrable), otherwise you can call [`Wait()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `Task` returned from the `InsertOneAsync` call to ensure your application stays around long enough to see the duplicate key exception:

```
commandsCollection.InsertOneAsync(doc).Wait();
```

If the insert fails because of a duplicate key, the `Wait()` will throw an `AggregateException` that contains a `MongoWriteException` that contains the duplicate key details.

```
try
{
    commandsCollection.InsertOneAsync(doc).Wait();
}
catch(AggregateException aggEx)
{
    aggEx.Handle(x => 
    { 
        var mwx = x as MongoWriteException;
        if (mwx != null && mwx.WriteError.Category == ServerErrorCategory.DuplicateKey) 
        {
            // mwx.WriteError.Message contains the duplicate key error message
            return true; 
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Similarly, if you're using `await`, that will throw an `AggregateException` as well.

To avoid the added complexity of the `AggregateException` wrapping the mongo exception, you can call `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `Wait()`:

```
try
{
    commandsCollection.InsertOneAsync(doc).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
catch(MongoWriteException mwx)
{
    if (mwx.WriteError.Category == ServerErrorCategory.DuplicateKey) 
    {
        // mwx.WriteError.Message contains the duplicate key error message
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I detect the duplicate key? InsertOneAsync will return a Task with no result part. And Wait will return a void.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing. How do I find the duplicate key information in a MongoWriteException?
`catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                e.Handle((x) =>
                {
                    if (x is MongoWriteException)
                    {
                    }
                    return true;
                });`

Comment: If a MongoWriteException is thrown, and the exception argument is named mwx, is it even possible mwx to be null?  In other words - is the mwx != null check really necessary?

Comment: @DevilDog74 Good catch -- edited. That was left over from the first implementation where  it was needed.

Comment: `await` will not throw an `AggregateException`. It will throw the actual exception.

Comment: it's odd, when I use `await` the thread exits with status 0 without exceptions and doesn't insert anything. but with Wait() I lose the async call purpose and it becomes a sync call but it works with the same code. the `InsertManyAsync` seem to be broken and not working asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

This is an async Task, you're missing the await

```
await commandsCollection.InsertOneAsync(bson);
```

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Okej, I added the await but now the C# program just terminates quiet where the insert is. I want a exception thrown in my face ^^

Comment: have you tried to explicitly save the collection? commandsCollection.Save()

Comment: Unfortunately such a command does not exists in the new version of the C# driver. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327856/how-to-insert-data-into-a-mongodb-collection-using-c) The second response.

Comment: Does it work when it's synchronous? Your code seems to be OK. Maybe it's a problem connecting to the server.

Comment: Yes, or I don't know what's happens. Because I insert the exact same values I can't determine of the values are the "new" ones or the "old" ones. And I can't seem to find any good documentation with the async methods.

Answer (score 1):

Further to @JonnyHK reply you can do the same when inserting many.

```
collection.InsertManyAsync(doc, new InsertManyOptions { IsOrdered = false }).Wait();
```

would be wrapped in try/catch;

```
try
{
    collection.InsertManyAsync(doc, new InsertManyOptions { IsOrdered = false }).Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException aggEx)
{
    aggEx.Handle(x =>
    {
        var mwx = x as MongoBulkWriteException;
        return mwx != null && mwx.WriteErrors.All(e => e.Category == ServerErrorCategory.DuplicateKey);
    });
}
```