# Can I get inserted record immediate after collection.InsertOneAsync(document) in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We are using MongoDB framework in C# for DB calls.
When we insert new document in collection, we want updated result with inserted _id into database.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102651/mongodb-server-v-2-6-7-with-c-sharp-driver-2-0-how-to-get-the-result-from-ins

Answer (score 1):

After you insert document using official C# driver, you already have it with updated `_id` column. Inserted document is updated by default.