# Identifying successful insertions using Mongo C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to identify a successful insertion into my mongo database, I have the options of using either InsertOne or InsertOneAsync. Neither according to the documentation returns a result though, so are there any options available to me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the method executes, the insertion was successful. Otherwise, the method will throw an exception.

Check out the related question: [MongoDB (server v 2.6.7) with C# driver 2.0: How to get the result from InsertOneAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102651/mongodb-server-v-2-6-7-with-c-sharp-driver-2-0-how-to-get-the-result-from-ins).

Comment: The document you inserted will also have the [BsonId] field populated (default name is `Id`) if you haven't already explicitly populated it.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB .NET Driver there is a WriteConcernResult class which is returned when you perform an insert. You can check whether or not it is OK. [WriteConcernResult](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_WriteConcernResult.htm)

**Update**
After another look there is a [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult) that returns the result of the insert operation when a single document is passed and a [BulkWriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#bulkwriteresults-insert) when an array of documents are passed.

Comment: I thought this too but the return type is void?